# jquery - load multiple external html in a loop on a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i was searching for the solution, but i cannot find any proper suggestions.

My goal is to loop different external urls on the same page (inside the div), rather than looping the pages with header option. Here is my current code for showing one external page in the div:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    function loadlink(){
        $('#tableHolder').load('read_data_from_page_one?v=1',function () {
             $(this).unwrap();
        });
    }

    loadlink(); // This will run on page load
    setInterval(function(){
        loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
    }, 30000);
    });
</script>
```

So after 30 seconds my div "tableholder" is refreshed, which is ok. Now i would like to add another external page after 5 minutes in the same div, and then after 5 minutes again another external page. They need to be refreshed every 30 seconds as my first external page. After that it needs to load again the first external page.

so basicly loop inside external content in a div. Is that possible?

The other solution is to loop the pages via header options:

```
<?php header("Refresh: 300; URL=read_data_from_page_two.php"); ?>
```

But i don't want that. Any suggestions?

Best regards, Misko

Comment: "Now i would like to add another external page after 5 minutes in the same div" -> What do you mean by "add"? Append at the end of `#tableHolder`?

Comment: no, i need to load external pages in a loop:

1.on load: page_one.php (refreshing after 30 sec)
2. after 5min: show page_two.php (and not showing the page_one.php), again refreshing the conntent of page_two every 30 sec. 
3. After 5 min (after 10 min on a page load): load content from page_three.php (and not showing the content from page_two.php), again refresing the content of a page_three.php every 30 sec.

Comment: Is the page limit fixed?

Comment: 4. After 5 min (after 15 min o a page load) show again the content of a page_one.php and refreshing it every 30 sec. And so on (so looping trough page_one, page_two, page_three)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If pages are numbered, simple counter will be fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 1, // current page
        max = 3; // last page
    function loadlink(){
        $('#tableHolder').load('read_data_from_page_one?v='+counter,function () {
            $(this).unwrap();
        });
    }

    loadlink(); // This will run on page load
    setInterval(loadlink, 30000); // this will run after every 30 seconds

    setInterval(function(){
        if(++counter > max){ // next page
            counter = 1; // back to start
        }
    }, 5000000); // 5 min interval
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This is what i was looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Is this more or less what you are meaning? An array of links that can be cycled through every `n` seconds and repeated when all have been displayed?

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

        var links=[
            'read_data_from_page_one?v=1',
            'read_data_from_page_two.php',
            'read_data_from_page_three.php',
            /*
                ..... etc
            */
            'read_data_from_page_ninetynine.php'
        ];
        var i=0;

        function loadlink(i){
            var url=links[i];

            $('#tableHolder').load( url, function() {
                 $(this).unwrap();
            });
        }

        loadlink(i);

        setInterval(function(){
            loadlink(i);
            i++;
            if( i>=links.length ) i=0;
        }, 30000 );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it's not loading any links, even if i use only array of two links.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function loadlink(x = 1){
        $('#tableHolder').load('read_data_from_page_one?v='+x,function () {
             $(this).unwrap();
        });
    }

    loadlink(); // This will run on page load

    var x=1;
    setInterval(function(){
        x++
        loadlink(x); // this will run after every 5 seconds
    }, 30000);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Working great, but you forgot to include refresh every 30 sec!

Comment: it's looping trough the links, but it's not refreshing the content as i wrote. Krzysiek gave the most accurate answer. But i really appreciate your effort!